# Laravel migration : Remove onDelete('cascade') from existing foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent

I have created a migration like this :

```
// ...
$table->foreign('a')->references('b')->on('c')->onDelete('cascade');
// ...
```

I want to remove the `onDelete('cascade')` in a new migration without breaking anything. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try to remove the old foreign key and add then add a new one without `onDelete`:

```
$table->dropForeign(['a']);
$table->foreign('a')->references('b')->on('c');
```

Answer (score 4):

To change a foreign key you must drop the foreign key and create it again. Unfortunately you can't modify a foreign key on MySQL