# Laravel how to modify onDelete('cascade') into no action in migration?

Tags: laravel, migration

I have a users table which has many debitur. I already set the user_id in debitur with onDelete('cascade').

```
Schema::table('debitur', function ($table) {
    $table->index('user_id');
    $table
    ->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade')
    ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Now I want to modify the `onDelete('cascade')` into `no action`, but the docs say for a `no action` I shouldn't have set `onDelete()`.

So how do I modify it? should I drop the foreign then set it again, or can I just re-run `schema::table` omitting the `onDelete()`?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167329/laravel-migration-remove-ondeletecascade-from-existing-foreign-key Hope it helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new migration:

```
Schema::table('debitur', function ($table) {
    $table->dropForeign('user_id');
    $table
    ->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('users')
    ->onUpdate('cascade');
}
```

Source: [Laravel Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: It works, except I have to set dropForeign('user_id') instead of dropForeign(['user_id']) which doesn't work (Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'debitur_user_id_foreign';
check that column/key exists).

Comment: `dropForeign(['user_id'])` should work. Because laravel documentation says to use an array here. Btw, answer edited.

Comment: is this solution (create new migration) for the existing table? is changing OnDelete in the old table?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you've already set onDelete('cascade') and now wanna change the action to NO ACTION.

Well, you've got to drop your previous foreign key and create another.

Here's my migration code.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('tablename', function ($table) {
        $table->dropForeign('tablename_id_foreign');
        $table->foreign('othertable_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('othertables')
            ->onDelete(\DB::raw('NO ACTION'));
    });
}
```